# To get the # token value from the url

Tags: spring, authentication, gwt, single-sign-on

We have a GWT based web application. There is a token value at the end of the application URL like
< URL >/#home.

We use SSO for user authentication and after the user gets successfully authenticated, the redirect URL becomes only < URL >, and the part after # gets removed.

This is only happening for the # values. As this is a GWT application so we need these token in the URL. Any suggestions?

Thank you.

Comment: You don't need the `token` into the `URL` you need to learn about the `SSO` solution you use, and how to retrive the `token`when the user is authenticated.

Comment: @Zorglube By the look of it, Vaishali is not talking about SSO tokens, but tokens that represent a place in the application. The problem is the # part is not sent to the server, so on redirect, the application loses its place.

Answer (score 0):

In modern GWT, the hash part of the URL can be retrieved using JsInterop and [Elemental2](https://github.com/google/elemental2) by calling:

```
elemental2.dom.DomGlobal.location.hash
```

In classic GWT (using `gwt-user.jar`), you can use:

```
com.google.gwt.user.client.Window.Location.getHash()
```

Answer (score 0):

The appropriate method to get the token would be:

```
com.google.gwt.user.client.History.getToken()
```

That is based on

```
com.google.gwt.user.client.Window.Location.getHash()
```

but it checks if the token is not null and not empty and then decodes it.